# How to show a quote fetched from api when Blazor Wasm loads (i:e on loading screen)?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I want to show quotes when the blazor wasm app loads. How to access this msg class. I have put the script in index.html header tag. But can't access this?

```html
<script>
  fetch("https://localhost:44359/data/Quotes.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.quotes));

  document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = "hey";
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <app>
    <div class="loading-page">
      <div class="quotes">
        <div class="msg"></div>
        <div class="author"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="loader mt-5">
        <div class="loader-dot dot1"></div>
        <div class="loader-dot dot2"></div>
        <div class="loader-dot dot3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app>


  <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

  <script>
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("service-worker.js");
  </script>

</body>
```

Is there any way ???

Comment: Do you plan to deploy in a static page or do you have a .Net core server ?

Comment: I didn't understand your question?? @aguafrommars

Comment: You idea is to provide a waiting screen wait the app load right ? With something than just "Loading..."

Comment: Yes to show quote in waiting screen than just boring Loading text

Comment: So, are you going to deploy the app to an ASP.Net Core server (IIS or kestrel) or to a static page without the possibility generate dynamically the html page.

Comment: Yes i will deploy it in server

Comment: If you use an ASP.Net Core server it easy, you just have to copy your index.html code in a .cshtml view and customize it to render the desired html code on server side without using a js script

Comment: The fallback url become this new page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
<body>
    <app><div id="message"></div></app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var quote = document.getElementById("message");
            fetch("sample-data/quotes.json")
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => quote.innerHTML = data[1].msg + "<br /><br />" + data[1].author);

         
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Create a folder named sample-data in the wwwroot folder and create in it a json file with the following data:

### quotes.json

```
    [
  {
    "msg": "It is a far, far better thing that I do, than I have ever done; it is a far, far better rest I go to than I have ever known.",
    "author": "Charles Dickens"

  },
  {
    "msg": "All we have to decide is what to do with the time that is given us.",
    "author": "J.R.R. Tolkein"

  },
  {
    "msg": "It matters not what someone is born, but what they grow to be.",
    "author": "J.K. Rowling"

  }
]
```

Note: You can insert whatever markup you want into the app element, including images, text sliders, etc.,  and do whatever manipulation you fancy... What is important, however, is that all your code should be within the immediate function, at the same location it is placed in the sample.